# Urllib problom: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'

Tags: python, anaconda, urllib

The environment is Win10 64-bit, Python 2.7.12, Anaconda.
The code is quite simple for web-scrapy:

```
import urllib

fhand = urllib.urlopen('http://www.reddit.com')
for line in fhand:
    print line.strip()
```

And the result is weird:

```
0.8475
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\catch-web.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "C:\Users\XxX\Anaconda2\lib\urllib.py", line 30, in <module>
    import base64
  File "C:\Users\XxX\Anaconda2\lib\base64.py", line 98, in <module>
    _urlsafe_encode_translation = string.maketrans(b'+/', b'-_')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

The code could run on the other PC with iPython, but could not work on this one. I have re-installed Anaconda for several times, but failed.

I would appreciate it if you could solve it.

Answer (score 0):

try Spyder, everything works.

still no idea for the problem.